# WordPress adding random strong tags, breaking divs, when accessed from google

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is extremely strange.

When I visit dfcmopen.com directly from the address bar, all is well. If I try to search for the site, then access it from google, I see the page code and a bunch of broken divs. Upon using the inspector, I see that  tags are being added randomly ie:

```
"        <"
<strong>d</strong>
"iv "
<strong>st</strong>
"yle="floa"
<strong>t</strong>
":left; position:relative; "
```

I can't seem to discover what is causing this issue, and its one I've never seen before.
Any ideas?

Comment: Update: it looks like "view source" isn't displaying this, so I'm assuming some JS is causing this issue. The questions are:

1. Why is this happening at all
2. Why is it happening when visiting the site from google, and not from typing in the url

Comment: The original dev of the site built it using "WP Cred" plugin

Comment: I had something similar, and found some erroneous markup in a custom field - so if anyone else gets it, maybe look there too.